# Can AWS or other cloud provider be used to cost-effectively transfer large files (+10TB) between Google Drive and Dropbox (via rclone command)?

Tags: cloud

Is there any service that could help me migrate a large collection of files between Google Drive and Dropbox? Or is every cloud provider billing their data transfer?

Comment: Pretty much every cloud provider will bill their data transfer... Cost effective however is subjective.  In AWS the data transfer for 1TB would probably cost you $90.  On Linode, their $5/month VPS comes with 1TB included.

Comment: yeah, that's what confuses me a lot. Back at uni, at work or in any other large organization in the city has amazing upload/download speeds, which spoiled me into taking it for granted. As Corona pandemic shown data caps of ISP providers are a bit bogus as well... why those high costs then? How to go about it then? Can one just spin up Linodes, Vultr and other cheap instances, transfer quickly and shut them down at no cost? That then sounds like administrative headaches... maybe terraform or som cross-cloud automation tool? running out of characters but so many questions...

Comment: I believe providers like Linode, the bandwidth is based on how long it is up for... So, if you only spin up the VPS for 1 day, you pay for bandwidth over 34GB, or something along those lines.  You do have a bit of playroom, for example, you get 1TB per $5/month vps.  So you could spin up 1x $5/month, bank the bandwidth, and use a $20/month vps for 1 hour a day, and at the end of the month pay $6, for a box 4x as powerful, and 1TB bandwidth...

Comment: it's crazy, but using Google Colab for example let me transfer TENS OF TERABYTES of data over internet at relatively high speed and no cost at all. Couple of European "niche" cloud providers like scaleway or Hetzner (?) offer unlimited bandwidth as well? What's going on